# Predict the future demand of product in multiple weeks

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

I wanted to create a Model which predict the future demand of each product in multiple weeks at each step (predict next year's weekly demand for each product)

I have a few small sizes (around 100-200 records) csv.

here information about the CSV columns:-
    The first column **makeId** represents the id of the product.
    The second column **areaId** represents an internal id of the location where the product is sold.
    The third column date represents the **date** in mm/dd/yyyy format.
    The fourth column **amount** represents the demand for the given product at the given area for a given week.

Sample File 1-

[image]

Sample File 2-

[image]

Sample File 3-

[image]

I thought of going with Arima model, but I m a bit confused about how to get data into a weekly format and use it to predict for each make id .

Any suggestion would be helpful, as I m new to time series problem

Comment: probably you need to go through: https://towardsdatascience.com/arima-forecasting-in-python-90d36c2246d3

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: From a quick glance at your examples, it looks like you already have weekly data. The following answer will help if that is not true, or if you are just looking to set your dataframe up to be able to use ARIMA models.

The quick answer to your question is: use the `pandas` package to read in/manipulate your data into a `dataframe` object, then use the `.resample()` method with the weekly frequency, e.g.: `.resample('W')`.

More details:

For time series analysis, most applications will benefit from setting the index of your data to the time variable. In your case, you can do this on reading in the data using `pandas`:

`import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your_data.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')`

If you cannot read it in, and need to change the dataframe in place, you can do:

`df = df.set_index('date')`

This assumes that the `date` column is set correctly as datetime object.

The next step is to resample the data so that you have a new value that captures the weekly activity in your data. This requires choosing a method to combine the data in your `Amount` field, since you want to show a value that may combine the values from multiple days. Here I'll choose the `mean()`, so that the new value is an average of the data of those days present during that week.

`df['Amount_weekly'] = df['Amount'].resample('W', how='mean')`

Since you are aggregating data, the function returns a new series, so here I am putting that new series into a new column in your `df`, that is `df['Amount_weekly']`.

As a result, you will have a time-series indexed dataframe with a column that shows the weekly-resampled data. This will be an appropriate format to use in ARIMA models in a package like `statsmodels.`